# remove decimal, following number(s) and round the values

Tags: php, regex

I have the following data.

```
$96.2k
$75.2k
$44.4k
$35.6k
Etc.......
```

What I am wanting to do is replace the decimal and any number(s) following the decimal. Then i want to round the whole number to the nearest tenth.

All of my data is between `10k` and `90k`

So the expected output would be..

```
$100k
$80k
$40k
$40k
```

I know i can use `preg_replace('/\.[0-9]+/', '', $data);` to remove the decimal and numbers but can i not use regular preg_replace with a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$number = '$96.2k';

$number = str_replace(array('$', 'k'), '', $number);
$number = round($number, -1); // -1 rounds to nearest 10

echo '$' . $number . 'k';
// $100k    

?>
```

More info on round here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace), I would use [`preg_replace_callback`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
$data = preg_replace_callback('/([0-9]+)\.[0-9]+/',   # capture first group of digits
      function($m) {                                  # $m is your captured match
         return round($m[1], -1);                     # round our captured match
      }, $data);
```

The will round your match (`$m`) to the nearest 10. Have a look at [`round`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) for the use of parameters.

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/60799)